# How to retrieve COM4J Requirement Coverage list

Tags: java, com4j

I am trying to get QC Requirement coverage by using COM4J. I am able to get list of test cases which ever covered the requirement but I don't know how to get the Test case id and name etc,

```
IReqFactory reqFactory=(itdc.reqFactory()).queryInterface(IReqFactory.class);
IReq iReq = (reqFactory.item(17447)).queryInterface(IReq.class);
System.out.println("Coverage count"+iReq.getCoverList(true).count());
System.out.println(iReq.name()+"Requirement Name"+iReq.id()+"Requirement Id");

IList list1=iReq.getCoverList(true);

for(int i=1;i<=list1.count();i++){
    //Com4jObject comobj = (Com4jObject)itr.next();
    System.out.println("Covered Tests : "+list1.iterator());
}
```

My Output is

```
Coverage count3
CAFE Core Functionality-750133Requirement Name17447Requirement Id
Covered Tests : 430171564
Covered Tests : 430171796
Covered Tests : 430172260
```

Here I need `Testcase` `id` and `name` instead of `Hashcode`. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code. Now I am getting required information.

ITestFactory sTestFactory = (itdc.testFactory()).queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);
            /*ITest iTest = (sTestFactory.item(23054)).queryInterface(ITest.class);
            //ITest iTest1= (sTestFactory.item(5)).queryInterface(ITest.class);
            System.out.println("Coverage List1 =" +iTest.getCoverList() + " test --> ");
            */

```
        IReqFactory reqFactory=(itdc.reqFactory()).queryInterface(IReqFactory.class);
        IReq iReq = (reqFactory.item(17447)).queryInterface(IReq.class);
        System.out.println("Coverage count"+iReq.getCoverList(true).count());
        System.out.println(iReq.name()+"Requirement Name"+iReq.id()+"Requirement Id");



        IList list1=iReq.getCoverList(true);
        for(int i=1;i<=list1.count();i++){
            System.out.println("Covered Tests : "+list1.iterator());
          }
        System.out.println("Requirement Coverage Status = "+iReq.hasCoverage());
        Iterator itr = list1.iterator();
        System.out.println(itr.getClass());
        IList list2=iReq.getCoverList(true);
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
           Com4jObject comObj =(Com4jObject)itr.next();
           ITestSet sTestSet = comObj.queryInterface(ITestSet.class);     
           ITest iTest = comObj.queryInterface(ITest.class);
           System.out.println(iTest.id()+"**************Name of the Test*************"+iTest.name()+"***********ids of the Test**************"+iTest.execStatus()+"***********Status of execution***********"+iTest.execDate()+"**********Executuion Date*********"+iTest.lastRun()+"***********");
```

}